# Large sparse dataset in Catboost

Tags: scikit-learn

I have a large sparse data matrix (bag of words, over large number of entries). I can easily treat it as a sparse matrix in `sklearn` models such as `RandomForest`. But, if I want to use `Catboost`, I need to turn it into a dense matrix. I was wondering if there is any efficient method to work with Catboost that doesn't cause this? For example, any internal built-in feature such as `TFRecords` of `Tensorflow`, to load bacthes.

Comment: See this issue: https://github.com/catboost/catboost/issues/1

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but as of catboost 0.17, sparse matrices are supported.

A `pandas.SparseDataFrame` or a `scipy.sparse.spmatrix` can be inputted as features X as described in the [updated documentation](https://catboost.ai/en/docs/concepts/python-reference_catboostclassifier_fit).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

1. what is the source of sparsity ? have you used one-hot encoder for example ? if so - you didn't need to do so when it comes to using boosting algorithm, so go back and feed the boosting with your original data.
2. you can always have a auto-encoder to dense your sparse matrix in TensorFlow and run a Boosting algorithm on the result. There are two pit fall in such approach 1) boosting algorithm are not good with continuous values which are the result of the auto-encoder 2) your auto-encoder is an approximate method which of course adds into the error model
3. consider designing your own network architecture which combines boosting and auto-encoder. For example a few layer to dense your sparse matrix and then a booster tree classifier similar to https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/estimator/boosted_trees - when you did so please update this answer.